# Pasar informacion a más de un Activity

Tags: android, kotlin

Necesito enviar informacion desde un Activity "A" a otro Activity "C" sin que esa info pase por el Activity "B". Al dar click en el boton desde el activity "A" se pasa al "B", pero la info se debe ir al "C".

No tengo idea como hacer algo asi. intente varias cosas pero nada me ha resultado.

```
val intent = Intent(this, ActivityB::class.java)
intent.putExtra(Info)
startActivity(intent)
```

Siempre he enviado la informacion de esa forma en kotlin pero ahora no se como podria hacerlo para que Info se vaya al Activity "C", pero que la siguiente pantalla que aparezca sea la "B"

**me disculpo si antes no fui muy claro preguntando**

Saludos

Comment: La pregunta no es lo suficientemente clara, puedes explicar más sobre tu caso y mostrar algo de código? Tambíen deberías leer [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para asegurarte de que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas. Y por qué colocas las etiquetas `java` y `kotlin`? En qué lenguaje quieres la respuesta?

Comment: De acuerdo con @SinneroftheSystem , la pregunta no es clara o no muy detallada, pero lo que puedes hacer es juntar las opciones seleccionadas y pasarlas en el `Intent`. Ahora que si buscas algo más Rx, puedes usar un `Replay Subject`. El `Observer` recibirá todos los valores emitidos por el `Subject`. Lo que podrías hacer es emitir valores desde Activity "A" y subscribir un `Observer` en Activity "B". Aquí un artículo que te podría ayudar. https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-rxjava-subject-publish-replay-behavior-and-async-subject-224d663d452f

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a lo que describes tienes esta secuencia  para abrir del la Activity A a la Activity C:

Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity C

y quieres enviar los datos de la A a la C pero sin pasar por B, si deseas enviar los datos usando un Intent simplemente indica la Activity destino, en este caso la ActivityC:

```
val intent = Intent(this, ActivityC::class.java)
intent.putExtra(Info)
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Pero si hago eso 
intent = Intent(this, ActivityC::class.java)
intent.putExtra(Info)
startActivity(intent)
me envia directamente al ActivityC y no al B .... osea el B se lo salta ...

Comment: Ok, para que deseas ir a Activity B por un momento? comentabas que no deseabas pasar por B

Comment: Es que en el ActivityB el usuario debe escojer entre un listado publicado en un recycler View y luego en el ActivityC se compararn algunos datos del usuario con lo que escogio en el ActivityB.

Mi problema es que en el B realice un adapter.java separado del Activity para cargar los datos de la Base de datos en el recycler View, entonces cuando sales del Activity B lo unico que envia al C es el ID de lo que seleccionaste en el recycler View.
Buscaba la forma que el ID del usuario se saltara el Activity B y se fuera directo al C para juntarlo con el ID de lo que escojes en el Activity B.